# How to format source code listings in the style of the Pragmatic Programmer book series using LaTeX?

Tags: formatting, latex

When I read Pragmatic Bookshelf books, it has the following format:

http://img210.imageshack.us/img210/2965/screenshot20100717at121.png

- How can I do that with LaTeX? Line numbers at the left side, coloring source code, and grayed source name.
- What's the tools for source code listing with LaTeX?

Comment: @Voter to close: On meta it was determined that LaTeX questions belong on SO. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/can-we-have-a-ruling-on-latex-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Although Stack Overflow is a perfectly good place to ask LaTeX questions currently, there is a proposal to set up a similar site specifically for TeX/LaTeX. Please [go here and "commit"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2148/tex-latex-and-friends?referrer=LtGW8MKLMIWU41zfK7oIpw2) if you would participate in such a website.

Comment: @Thomas: questioner who wants latex q's on s.o. accepts an answer opining latex q's belong on s.o. = "it was determined on meta that..."

Comment: @Cirno de Bergerac: Not just that... look at the other answers and the votes. There seems to be a general concensus.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*The* package for formatting source code in LaTeX is [listings](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings). Check out what it can do in its manual [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf).

This is how close I managed to get:

[image: The listing, as typeset in LaTeX]

The filename from the caption is also the target of the `Download` link. Sorry about the lack of round corners. Those can probably be done with TikZ.

Here's the preamble:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage{tgadventor}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\definecolor{lineno}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{code}{rgb}{0,0.1,0.6}
\definecolor{keyword}{rgb}{0.5,0.1,0.1}
\definecolor{titlebox}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}
\definecolor{download}{rgb}{0.8,0.1,0.5}
\definecolor{title}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}

\lstset{
    language=Lisp,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small\color{code},
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    numbers=left,
    firstnumber=1,
    stepnumber=5,
    numberfirstline=true,
    numberstyle=\color{lineno}\sffamily\scriptsize,
    keywordstyle=\color{keyword}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\itshape,
    morekeywords={dosync,if},
    deletekeywords={alter}
}

\makeatletter
\gdef\lst@SkipOrPrintLabel{%
    \ifnum\lst@skipnumbers=\z@
        \global\advance\lst@skipnumbers-\lst@stepnumber\relax
        \lst@PlaceNumber
        \lst@numberfirstlinefalse
    \else
        \lst@ifnumberfirstline
            {\def\thelstnumber{Line \@arabic\c@lstnumber}\lst@PlaceNumber}%
            \lst@numberfirstlinefalse
        \else
            {\def\thelstnumber{-}\lst@PlaceNumber}%
        \fi
    \fi
    \global\advance\lst@skipnumbers\@ne}%
\def\lst@maketitle#1{
   \vskip\abovecaptionskip
   \colorbox{titlebox}{
       \scriptsize
       \color{download}\ttfamily\href{http://example.com/#1}{Download}
       \color{title}\sffamily\bfseries#1}
   \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\makeatother
```

Then, typeset a listing in the body with:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[title=examples/introduction.clj]
(defn hello
  "Writes hello message to *out*. Calls you by username.
  Knows if you have been here before."
  [username]
  (dosync
    (let [past-visitor (@visitors username)]
      (if past-visitor
        (str "Welcome back, " username)
        (do
          (alter visitors conj username)
          (str "Hello, " username))))))
\end{lstlisting}
```

I love LaTeX.

Comment: It's pretty cool, but as I've updated with my question. Could you look into why the caption part is kinda different?

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong code. You should use `title` instead of `caption`. I only hacked `\lst@maketitle`, not `\lst@makecaption`. Edited.